# Add unordered list below form checkbox

Tags: 7, forms

I was wondering if anyone knows how to add an unordered list after/below the checkbox label.
So the label would have sub-labels to them.  I would image that the code would look something like this, but this is just pseudo code?

```
 $form['checkbox'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Checkbox Title'),
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#options' => array(
        'option1' => array(
           'title' => 'option1',
           '#options' = > array(
             'sub-option1' => t('sub-option1'),
             'sub-option2' => t('sub-option2'), 
           ),          
        ),
        'option2' => array(
           'title' => 'option2',
           '#options' = > array(
             'sub-option1' => t('sub-option1'),
             'sub-option2' => t('sub-option2'), 
           ),          
        ),
     ),
 );
```

Comment: What it sounds like you're after is two separate form elements within a fieldset (form api type).

Comment: OK, the thing that troubles me about that approach is that this is a content type I am attaching this to. So I am using hook_form_alter to alter the content type form and I want to add a dynamic unordered list to the options in the checkbox.

Comment: I am thinking of adding a HTML unordered list to the value portion of the option.  This seems like it might work, but does not seem appropriate.

Comment: You can do a hook_form_alter, add the field, and programmatically add the #options.  So the options themselves can be dynamic.